# R. ggplot2. Recreating smooth curve from stat_smooth method

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I am trying to recreate the procedure which is used for estimating smooth function from stat_smooth in ggplot2 package. Lets take an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 100
X <- runif(n)*8
Y <- sin(3*X) + cos(X^2) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)

myData <- as.data.frame(cbind(X, Y))

p <- ggplot(myData, aes(y=Y, x=X)) + 
     stat_smooth(se = FALSE, size = 2) +
     geom_point(size = 1)
p
geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is <1000, so using loess. Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.
```

[image]

The smooth line doesn't really fit the data, but it doesn't matter. Now, lets recreate the same graph from scratch. According to http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/loess we need to use tricubic weighting kernel and polynomial of degree 2 (by default). I found this [http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~peterf/MATH38011/NPR%20local%20Linear%20Estimator.pdf](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/%7Epeterf/MATH38011/NPR%20local%20Linear%20Estimator.pdf) article which describes how to estimate smooth loess function. I try to recreate this method and use it on my data:

```
Dfct <- function(t){
  if (abs(t) <= 1)
  ((1-abs(t)^3)^3) else
  0
  }

K_h <- function(x_0, x){
  f_hat <- NULL
  Dfct(abs(x - x_0)/h)
  }

m_hat_loess <- function(X, Y){
  e_1 <- c(1, 0, 0)
  m_hat <- NULL

  for(i in 1:length(X)){
  K_h_vector <- NULL

  for(j in 1:length(X)){
    K_h_vector <- c(K_h_vector, K_h(X[i], X[j]))
    }

  X_0 <- cbind(rep(1, length(X)), (X - X[i]), (X - X[i])^2)
  W <- diag(K_h_vector)

  m_hat <- c(m_hat,
  t(e_1)%*% solve(t(X_0)%*%W%*%X_0) %*% (t(X_0)%*%W%*%Y)
  )
}
m_hat
}
```

I am not sure what I should use for parameter *h*, but according to a book I have "For tri-cube kernel with metric width, *h* is the radius of the support region." Hence the first thing I try is:

```
h <- (max(X)-min(X))/2
Y_hat <- m_hat_loess(X, Y)

tempData <- as.data.frame(cbind(X, Y_hat))
ggplot(tempData , aes(x=X, y=Y_hat)) +
  geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

This is clearly not the same function. I have been using different values of *h* but couldn't recreate the same curve, which makes me believe that I made a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stat_smooth(...)` function in the `ggplot` package merely passes your data (potentially subsetted) to the `loess(...)` function, as can be demonstrated here:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
X <- runif(n)*8
Y <- sin(3*X) + cos(X^2) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)

myData <- data.frame(X,Y)
fit <- loess(Y~X,data=myData)
myData$pred <- predict(fit)

ggplot(myData, aes(X,Y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(se=F, size=3)+
  geom_line(aes(X,pred),colour="yellow")
```

[image]

The [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/loess.html) for `loess(...)` provides references to the method of calculation, specifically, [here](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/departments/sia/doc/smoothing.springer.pdf).